# Python elif to nested if

Tags: python

I have made this program using elif statements and am just curious on how it would be done using nested ifs instead.

The user has to input a number and the program will tell them which month it is and how many days are in it.

```
month_num = int(input("Enter the number of a month (Jan = 1) : "))

if month_num == 1:
    print(month_num, "is Feburary, and has 29 days.")

elif month_num == 2:
    print(month_num, "is January, and has 31 days.")

elif month_num == 3:
    print(month_num, "is March, and has 31 days.")

elif month_num == 4:
    print(month_num, "is April, and has 30 days.")

elif month_num == 5:
    print(month_num, "is May, and has 31 days.")

elif month_num == 6:
    print(month_num, "is June, and has 30 days.")

elif month_num == 7:
    print(month_num, "is July, and has 31 days.")

elif month_num == 8:
    print(month_num, "is August, and has 31 days.")

elif month_num == 9:
    print(month_num, "is September, and has 30 days.")

elif month_num == 10:
    print(month_num, "is october, and has 31 days.")

elif month_num == 11:
    print(month_num, "is November, and has 30 days.")

elif month_num == 12:
    print(month_num, "is december, and has 31 days.")

else:
    print(month_num, "Is not a valid number")
```

Comment: You are only comparing a single value, why would you want nested `if`(s)?

Comment: With nested `if`s the result for `1` and `2` would be wrong as well, but less easier to correct.

Comment: You could, but you would need a lot more if-else statements.

Comment: I suggest that you look into _dictionaries_ rather than nested `if`s

Comment: ie: if month is not 1, then if month is not 2, then if month is not 3 ..., else print 3, else print 2, else print 1

Comment: not talking about mistake that you have: February as 1st and January as 2nd month of a year; this is great example of how not to write a code

Answer (score 1):

Neither are a good solution. You'd be better off creating a dictionary.

Assuming f-strings are available (Python >= 3.6). If not these can be easily converted to use `.format`:

```
month_num = int(input("Enter the number of a month (Jan = 1) : "))

d = {1: ('January', 31),
     2: ('February', 29),
     ...
     }

try:
    month_name, num_of_days = d[month_num]
    print(f'{month_num} is {month_name}, and has {num_of_days} days')
except KeyError:
    print(month_num, "Is not a valid number")
```

Also note that February does not always have 29 days.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`calendar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html), i.e.:

```
import calendar as cal
from datetime import date
m = int(input("Enter the number of a month (Jan = 1) : "))
if m in range(1,13):
  print(f"{m} is {cal.month_name[m]} and has {cal.monthrange(date.today().year, m)[1]} days.")
```

---

```
1 is January and has 31 days.
2 is February and has 29 days.
3 is March and has 31 days.
4 is April and has 30 days.
5 is May and has 31 days.
6 is June and has 30 days.
7 is July and has 31 days.
8 is August and has 31 days.
9 is September and has 30 days.
10 is October and has 31 days.
11 is November and has 30 days.
12 is December and has 31 days.
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/2696372ae5)

Comment: You can use `monthlen(2020, m)` instead of `monthrange(2020, m)[1]`

Comment: I don't' think `calendar` has a `monthlen` method, does it?

Comment: It does. No idea why it is not documented though.

Comment: I tried it before posting my comment and python 3.6.8 doesn't seem to have it. https://trinket.io/python3/4f60dc71c1 Which version are you using?

Comment: Did a bit of a research. It might have been introduced in 3.7, and it was supposed to be "private" (prefixed with `_`): https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/1149791267116556288